# É possível reusar esta função complexa para múltiplos cadastros ao mesmo tempo?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, select, sql-insert

No site que assumi de um desenvolvedor anterior, faz-se o cadastro de investidores um por um após uma busca no sistema chamado CM. A função chama-se cadastraInvestidor:

```
function cadastraInvestidor(codigoCM){ // TODO 2/4/2015 - Cadastro de investidor com código CM
$.ajax({
      async: true, cache:false, 
      url: '[:raiz]cadAdmin/getDetalhesInvestidorCM',
      data: {
          codigoCM: codigoCM
      },
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
          if (data == 'erro'){
                 $("#erroInvestidorJaCadastrado").dialog( {
                    buttons : {
                        Ok : function() {
                            $(this).dialog('close');
                        }
                    },
                    modal : true,
                    autoOpen : false,
                    resizable : false,
                    closeOnEscape : false,
                    open : function(event, ui) {
                        $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
                    }
                 });    
                 $("#erroInvestidorJaCadastrado").dialog('open');
          } else {
                var arrayContatos = new Array();
                var close = $('#lblCancelar').val();
                var save = $('#lblSalvar').val();
                var dialog_buttons = {};  

                dialog_buttons[close] = function(){
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                };
                dialog_buttons[save] = function(){

                    $.ajax({
                          async: true, cache:false, 
                          url: '[:raiz]cadAdmin/validaEmailInvestidorCM',
                          data: {
                              codigoCM: codigoCM
                          },
                          dataType: 'json',
                          success: function(dt) {

                              var info = new Array();
                              info[0] = $('#lblInfo0').val();
                              info[1] = $('#lblInfoConfDadosCM1').val();
                              info[2] = $('#lblInfoSalvaInvest2').val();
                              info[3] = $('#lblInfoSalvaInvest3').val();
                              info[4] = $('#lblInfoSalvaInvest4').val();
                              info[5] = $('#lblInfoSalvaInvest5').val();
                              info[6] = $('#lblInfoSalvaInvest6').val();
                              info[7] = $('#lblInfoSalvaInvest7').val();
                              info[8] = $('#lblInfoSalvaInvest8').val();
                              info[9] = $('#lblInfoSalvaInvest9').val();
                              info[10] = $('#lblInfo9').val();
                              info[11] = $('#lblInfoCom7').val();
                              info[12] = $('#lblInfo11').val();
                              info[13] = $('#lblInfoCom8').val();
                              info[14] = $('#lblInfoConfDadosCM25').val();
                              info[15] = $('#lblInfo12').val();

                              data['info']=info;

                              if(dt=='1'){  //VALIDAÇÃO EMAIL DT=0 CERTO DT=1 ERRADO DT=2 E-MAIL EM BRANCO
                                  $("#erroEmail").dialog( {
                                        buttons : {
                                            Ok : function() {
                                                $(this).dialog('close');
                                            }
                                        },
                                        modal : true,
                                        autoOpen : false,
                                        resizable : false,
                                        closeOnEscape : false,
                                        width: 500,
                                        height: 120,
                                        open : function(event, ui) {
                                            $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
                                        }
                                     });                                      
                                  $('#erroEmail').dialog('open');
                              }
                                else if(dt=='0') {
                                    $.ajax({
                                          async: true, cache:false, 
                                          url: '[:raiz]cadAdmin/cadastraInvestidorCM',
                                        //  data: ({
                                             data : data,
                                        //}),
                                          type: "POST",
                                          dataType: 'json',
                                          success: function(dados) {

                                             $("#erroUhSemUnidade,#sucessoSalvaCM,#erroEmailInvestidor,#erroLoginInvestidor").dialog( {
                                                buttons : {
                                                    Ok : function() {
                                                        $(this).dialog('close');
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                modal : true,
                                                autoOpen : false,
                                                resizable : false,
                                                closeOnEscape : false,
                                                width: 500,
                                                open : function(event, ui) {
                                                    $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
                                                }
                                             });    

                                              $.ajax({
                                                  cache:false, 
                                                  data: ({
                                                          codigoCM: codigoCM,
                                                          preferencias: (data['tipo'] == 'F' ? $('#txtPreferenciasF').val() : $('#txtPreferenciasJ').val()),
                                                          comportamento: (data['tipo'] == 'F' ? $('#txtComportamentoF').val() : $('#txtComportamentoJ').val()) 
                                                  }),
                                                  url: '[:raiz]cadAdmin/salvaInfoInvestidorCodigoCM',
                                                  dataType: 'json',
                                                  success: function(dt) {                   
                                                        //$('#modalDadosSalvos').dialog('open');
                                                      $.ajax({
                                                          cache:false, 
                                                          data: ({
                                                                  codigoCM: codigoCM,
                                                                  arrayContatos : arrayContatos,
                                                          }),
                                                          type: "POST",
                                                          url: '[:raiz]cadAdmin/salvaContatoInvestidor',
                                                          dataType: 'json',
                                                      });
                                                  }
                                              });
                                              if(dados != null && dados != ""){
                                                  if (dados == '2'){
                                                      $("#erroEmailInvestidor").dialog('open');
                                                  } 
                                                  else if (dados == '3') {
                                                      $("#erroLoginInvestidor").dialog('open');
                                                  }
                                                  else {
                                                      if(dados.split("|")[1] != ''){
                                                          var dadosSplit = dados.split("|");
                                                          var tam = dadosSplit.length;
                                                          var erros ='';
                                                          for ( var int = 0; int < (tam-1); int++) {
                                                              erros+=' '+dadosSplit[int];
                                                              if (int != (tam-2)){
                                                                  erros+=',';
                                                              }
                                                          }
                                                          $("#erroUhSemUnidade").html($('#errosalva').val()+erros);
                                                          $("#erroUhSemUnidade").dialog('open');
                                                      }else{

                                                          $("#erroUhSemUnidade").html($('#errosalva').val()+dados.split("|")[0]);
                                                          $("#erroUhSemUnidade").dialog('open');
                                                      }
                                                  }
                                              }else{
                                                  $("#sucessoSalvaCM").dialog('open');
                                              }
                                              $( "#modalDetalhes" ).dialog( "close" );
                                          }
                                    });
                                }else if(dt=='2'){
                                    $("#emailEmBranco").dialog( {
                                        buttons : {
                                            Ok : function() {
                                                $(this).dialog('close');
                                            }
                                        },
                                        modal : true,
                                        autoOpen : false,
                                        resizable : false,
                                        closeOnEscape : false,
                                        width: 500,
                                        open : function(event, ui) {
                                            $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
                                        }
                                     });                                        
                                    $("#emailEmBranco").dialog('open');
                                }
                          }
                    });
                };
                $('#bodyInvestidoresUh').html("");
                $('#bodyInvestidoresUhJ').html("");
                if(data['dataNascimento'] != 'NULL'){
                      var nasc = data['dataNascimento'].split("-");
                      nasc = nasc[2]+"/"+nasc[1]+"/"+nasc[0];
                  }else{
                    var nasc = 'NULL';
                  }

                if (data['tipo'] == 'F'){
                      var checkBox = "";
                      var tamanhoModal = 670 + (50 * parseInt(data['uhs'].length));
                      $('#detalhesFisica').show();
                      $('#detalhesJuridica').hide();
                      $('#modalDetalhes').attr('title',$('#lblDetalhesInvestidor').val());
                      $('#modalDetalhes').dialog({
                            width: 625,
                            height: tamanhoModal,
                            modal: true,
                            buttons: dialog_buttons,
                            autoOpen: true,
                            resizable: false,
                            closeOnEscape: true,
                            position: 'top',
                            close: function(){

                            }
                      });

                      $('#txtPreferenciasF').val("");
                      $('#txtComportamentoF').val("");

                      $('#lblFisicaNome').html(data['nome'].toString().toUpperCase() == 'NULL' ? '' : data['nome'].toString());                   
                      $('#lblFisicaCPF').html(data['documento'].toString().toUpperCase() == 'NULL' ? '' : data['documento'].toString());
                      $('.lblFisicaDataNascimento').html(nasc.toUpperCase() == 'NULL' ? '' : nasc.toString());
                      $('#lblFisicaEmail').html(data['email'].toString().toUpperCase() == 'NULL' ? '' : data['email'].toString());
                      $('#lblFisicaTelefone').html(data['telefone'].toString().toUpperCase() == 'NULL' ? '' : data['telefone'].toString());
                      $('#lblFisicaLogradouro').html(data['logradouro'].toString().toUpperCase() == 'NULL' ? '' : data['logradouro'].toString());
                      $('#lblFisicaBairro').html(data['bairro'].toString().toUpperCase() == 'NULL' ? '' : data['bairro'].toString());                     
                      $('#lblFisicaCidade').html(data['cidade'].toString().toUpperCase() == 'NULL' ? '' : data['cidade'].toString());
                      $('#lblFisicaEstado').html(data['estado'].toString().toUpperCase() == 'NULL' ? '' : data['estado'].toString());
                      $('#lblFisicaPais').html(data['pais'].toString().toUpperCase() == 'NULL' ? '' : data['pais'].toString());
                      $('#lblFisicaCargo').html(data['cargo'].toString().toUpperCase() == 'NULL' ? '' : data['cargo'].toString());
                      $('#lblFisicaCC').html(data['contaCorrente'].toString().toUpperCase() == 'NULL' ? '' : data['contaCorrente'].toString());
                      $('#lblFisicaAgencia').html(data['agencia'].toString().toUpperCase() == 'NULL' ? '' : data['agencia'].toString());
                      $('#lblFisicaBanco').html(data['banco'].toString().toUpperCase() == 'NULL' ? '' : data['banco'].toString());

                      $('#tableInvestidoresUh').show();
                      var retorno = "";
                      //$('#bodyInvestidoresUh').html(retorno);

                      for ( var int = 0; int < data['uhs'].length; int++) {
                            retorno += "<tr>";
                            if((data['uhs'][int]['numero']).match(/^S.*$/)){
                                retorno += "<td>"+ 'Office' +"</td>";
                            } else if ((data['uhs'][int]['numero']).match(/^L.*$/) || (data['uhs'][int]['numero']).match(/^B.*$/)){
                                retorno += "<td>"+ 'Outros' + "</td>";
                            } else {
                            retorno += "<td>"+ (data['uhs'][int]['tipoinvestidor'] == 'P' ? 'Pool' : 'Condomínio') +"</td>";
                            }
                            retorno += "<td>"+data['uhs'][int]['numero']+" - "+data['uhs'][int]['desctipo']+"</td>";
                            retorno += "<td>"+data['uhs'][int]['unidade']+"</td>";
                            retorno += "<td>"+data['uhs'][int]['descricao']+"</td>";
                            retorno += "<td>"+data['uhs'][int]['participacao']+"</td>";
                            retorno += "</tr>";
                      }
                     $('#bodyInvestidoresUh').html(retorno);

                     var contato =0;
                     $.ajax({
                            async: false, cache:false, 
                            url: '[:raiz]cadAdmin/getContatoInvestidorCm',
                            data: {
                                codCm: codigoCM
                            },
                            dataType: 'json',
                            success: function(dt) {
                                var contactTable = "";
                                if (dt[0]!=undefined && dt[0]['COUNT'] > 0){
                                    contato = dt[0]['COUNT'];
                                    $('#txt0DadosContato').show();
                                    contactTable+="<table class='tables' style='width:565px;float:left;font-size: 11px;'><tr><td>"+$('#lblNome').val()+"</td>" +
                                            "<td>"+$('#lblTel').val()+"</td><td>"+$('#lblEmail').val()+"</td></tr>";
                                    for(var i=0;i<dt.length;i++){
                                        arrayContatos[i] = dt[i]['NOME']+"|"+dt[i]['TELEFONE'] +"|"+ dt[i]['EMAIL']+";";
                                        var nome = (dt[i]['NOME']!=undefined ? dt[i]['NOME'] : "");
                                        var telefone = (dt[i]['TELEFONE']!=undefined ? dt[i]['TELEFONE'] : "");
                                        var email = (dt[i]['EMAIL']!=undefined ? dt[i]['EMAIL'] : "");
                                        contactTable+=("<tr><td>" + nome + " </td><td> " + telefone + " </td><td> " + email +"</td></tr>");
                                    }
                                    contactTable+="</table>";
                                    $('#txt1DadosContato').show();
                                }else{
                                    $('#txt1DadosContato').hide();
                                }
                                $('.dadosContato').html(contactTable);
                            }
                        }); 
                     var tamanhoModal = (670 + (45 * ((parseInt(data['uhs'].length)>0 ?parseInt(data['uhs'].length)+2 : 0 ))
                             + ((contato>0 ? contato+2 : 0)*20))*1.22); 
                     $('#detalhesFisica').show();
                     $('#detalhesJuridica').hide();
                     $('#modalDetalhes').attr('title',$('#lblDetalhesInvestidor').val());
                     $('#modalDetalhes').dialog({
                            width: 625,
                            height: tamanhoModal,
                            modal: true,
                            buttons: dialog_buttons,
                            autoOpen: true,
                            resizable: false,
                            closeOnEscape: true,
                            position: 'top',
                            close: function(){

                            }
                        });
                } else {
                      var checkBox = "";

                      $('#txtPreferenciasJ').val("");
                      $('#txtComportamentoJ').val("");                          

                      $('#lblJuridicaNome').html(data['nome'].toString().toUpperCase() == 'NULL' ? '' : data['nome'].toString());
                      $('.lblFisicaDataNascimento').html(nasc.toUpperCase() == 'NULL' ? '' : nasc.toString());
                      $('#lblJuridicaCNPJ').html(data['documento'].toString().toUpperCase() == 'NULL' ? '' : data['documento'].toString());
                      $('#lblJuridicaRazaoSocial').html(data['razaoSocial'].toString().toUpperCase() == 'NULL' ? '' : data['razaoSocial'].toString());
                      $('#lblJuridicaTipo').html(data['tipo'].toString().toUpperCase() == 'NULL' ? '' : (data['tipo'].toString().localeCompare('F') == 0 ? "Física" : "Jurídica"));
                      $('#lblJuridicaEmpresa').html(data['empresa'].toString().toUpperCase() == 'NULL' ? '' : data['empresa'].toString());
                      $('#lblJuridicaEmail').html(data['email'].toString().toUpperCase() == 'NULL' ? '' : data['email'].toString());
                      $('#lblJuridicaTelefone').html(data['telefone'].toString().toUpperCase() == 'NULL' ? '' : data['telefone'].toString());                 
                      $('#lblJuridicaLogradouro').html(data['logradouro'].toString().toUpperCase() == 'NULL' ? '' : data['logradouro'].toString());
                      $('#lblJuridicaBairro').html(data['bairro'].toString().toUpperCase() == 'NULL' ? '' : data['bairro'].toString());         
                      $('#lblJuridicaCidade').html(data['cidade'].toString().toUpperCase() == 'NULL' ? '' : data['cidade'].toString());
                      $('#lblJuridicaEstado').html(data['estado'].toString().toUpperCase() == 'NULL' ? '' : data['estado'].toString());
                      $('#lblJuridicaPais').html(data['pais'].toString().toUpperCase() == 'NULL' ? '' : data['pais'].toString());
                      $('#lblJuridicaCargo').html(data['cargo'].toString().toUpperCase() == 'NULL' ? '' : data['cargo'].toString());
                      $('#lblJuridicaCC').html(data['contaCorrente'].toString().toUpperCase() == 'NULL' ? '' : data['contaCorrente'].toString());
                      $('#lblJuridicaAgencia').html(data['agencia'].toString().toUpperCase() == 'NULL' ? '' : data['agencia'].toString());
                      $('#lblJuridicaBanco').html(data['banco'].toString().toUpperCase() == 'NULL' ? '' : data['banco'].toString());

                      $('#tableInvestidoresUhJ').show();
                      var retorno = "";
                      //$('#bodyInvestidoresUhJ').html(retorno);
                      for ( var int = 0; int < data['uhs'].length; int++) {
                        retorno += "<tr>";
                        if ((data['uhs'][int]['desctipo']).match(/^S.*$/)){
                            retorno += "<td>"+ 'Office' +"</td>";
                        } else if ((data['uhs'][int]['desctipo']).match(/^L.*$/) || (data['uhs'][int]['desctipo']).match(/^B.*$/)){
                            retorno += "<td>"+ 'Outros' + "</td>";
                        } else {
                            retorno += "<td>"+ (data['uhs'][int]['tipoinvestidor'] == 'P' ? 'Pool' : 'Condomínio') +"</td>";
                        }
                        retorno += "<td>"+data['uhs'][int]['desctipo']+"</td>";
                        retorno += "<td>"+data['uhs'][int]['unidade']+"</td>";
                        retorno += "<td>"+data['uhs'][int]['descricao']+"</td>";
                        retorno += "<td>"+data['uhs'][int]['participacao']+"</td>";
                        retorno += "</tr>";
                      }
                     $('#bodyInvestidoresUhJ').html(retorno);
                     //iniciaDataTableUH("tableInvestidoresUhJ", 1, "desc");

                        var contato = 0;
                        $.ajax({
                            async: false, cache:false, 
                            url: '[:raiz]cadAdmin/getContatoInvestidor',
                            data: {
                                codCm: codigoCM
                            },
                            dataType: 'json',
                            success: function(dt) {
                                var contactTable = "";
                                if (dt[0]!=undefined && dt[0]['COUNT'] > 0){
                                    contato = dt[0]['COUNT'];
                                    $('#txt0DadosContato').show();
                                    contactTable+="<table class='tables' style='width:565px;float:left;font-size: 11px;'><tr><td>"+$('#lblNome').val()+"</td>" +
                                            "<td>"+$('#lblTel').val()+"</td><td>"+$('#lblEmail').val()+"</td></tr>";
                                    for(var i=0;i<dt.length;i++){
                                        arrayContatos[i] = dt[i]['NOME']+"|"+dt[i]['TELEFONE'] +"|"+ dt[i]['EMAIL']+";";
                                        var nome = (dt[i]['NOME']!=undefined ? dt[i]['NOME'] : "");
                                        var telefone = (dt[i]['TELEFONE']!=undefined ? dt[i]['TELEFONE'] : "");
                                        var email = (dt[i]['EMAIL']!=undefined ? dt[i]['EMAIL'] : "");
                                        contactTable+=("<tr><td>" + nome + " </td><td> " + telefone + " </td><td> " + email +"</td></tr>");
                                    }
                                    contactTable+="</table>";
                                    $('#txt0DadosContato').show();
                                }else{
                                    //dar um hide no contato caso o investidor seja pessoa f�sica
                                    $('#txt0DadosContato').hide();
                                }                                   
                                $('.dadosContato').html(contactTable);
                            }
                        }); 

                    //var tamanhoModal = (690 + (50 * parseInt(data['uhs'].length) + (contato*20))*1.22);
                    var tamanhoModal = (670 + (45 * ((parseInt(data['uhs'].length)>0 ?parseInt(data['uhs'].length)+2 : 0 ))
                             + ((contato>0 ? contato+2 : 0)*20))*1.22); 
                    $('#detalhesJuridica').show();
                    $('#detalhesFisica').hide();    
                    $('#modalDetalhes').attr('title',$('#lblDetalhesInvestidor').val());
                    $('#modalDetalhes').dialog({
                        width: 625,
                        height: tamanhoModal,
                        modal: true,
                        buttons: dialog_buttons,
                        autoOpen: true,
                        resizable: false,
                        closeOnEscape: true,
                        position: 'top',
                        close: function(){

                        }
                    });                         
                }
            }
      }
});
}
```

Sei que a função é tanto quanto complexa, já que é diferente pra cadastro de pessoa física como jurídica.

Como a função funciona perfeitamente, será que é possível criar um botão com uma função pra cadastrar vários investidores da busca realizada ao mesmo tempo?

Comment: A função é bem grande mesmo.. mas será que tinha a necessidade de postá-la inteira aqui? Poderia talvez simplificar e colocar só o que é importante, por exemplo o nome das funções e etc.

Comment: Realmente... https://image-pd.s3.envato.com/files/38522860/_MG_1248.jpg

Comment: Mas agora, falando sério... Se esta chamada `$.ajax` inicial já fosse o cadastro completo, seria bem simples de criar um botão para cadastrar todas, mas - pelo visto - depois de efetuar a chamada, ele abre outras dialogs, que por sua vez, fazem outras chamadas e assim por diante, então, não me parece que dê pra automatizar isso, já que requer mais input do usuário. Ou estou enganado?

Comment: OK, desculpem. Sei que é exagero postar a função toda. Normalmente o cadastrarInvestidor resulta em abrir uma caixa de diálogo pra confirmar se os dados a serem cadastrados estão corretos. Depois vem escolher entre salvar (que faz o cadastro) e cancelar. E em alguns casos não abre essa caixa de diálogo se o investidor já estiver cadastrado. A ideia de automatização seria simplesmente ativar a cadastrarInvestidor pra depois poder salvar e assim sucessivamente. Se não souberem como, não tem problema. Não custou tentar, hehehe

Answer (score 1):

Do jeito que está, **não** me parece possível reaproveitar a função para múltiplos cadastros simultâneos.

Alguns problemas que consigo identificar:

- **Dependência da interface para a lógica**: o problema mais grave do meu ponto de vista. Não existe uma separação lógica dos dados processados e os componentes da página, o que torna muito difícil fazer reuso de qualquer trecho.
- **Quase inexistência de modularidade**: embora o código *funcione*, parece não haver qualquer divisão do processo em sub-rotinas ou "passos" distinguíveis.
- **Fluxo de dados fracamente definido**: é difícil identificar quais dados são usados em cada passo da rotina, ou seja, quais as entradas e saídas de cada fase da pesquisa e do cadastro.

Com base nos itens acima, diria que sem uma reformulação da rotina não é viável realizar vários simultaneamente.

Sugiro uma solução nos seguintes termos:

1. **Refatore o código**. Isso significa mudar sem afetar o comportamente. No entanto, faça isso de forma que cada parte do cadastro seja feita em rotinas separadas. A pesquisa deve ficar numa rotina, a validação de data em outra, os pequenos cadastros em outras, etc. Cada rotina deve ter bem definido os seus parâmetros de entrada e saída, isto é, **não use variáveis globais**. Essas rotinas não devem ler ou afetar o estado da página. Toda a orquestração de componentes visuais deve continuar numa lógica central.
2. **Livre-se dos diálogos**. Agora pense em como você pode apresentar as informações sem uso de diálogos. Diálogos são práticos, porém para processamento em paralelo ou sequencial são um grande problema, afinal só uma informação pode ser exibida por vez. Uma solução simples é gerar algum tipo de log ou tabela de erros, ou ainda, no caso de haver uma tabela com os resultados da pesquisa, mostrar os erros numa coluna para cada linha que está selecionada. Uma idéia é mostrar uma imagem de sucesso ou erro para cada linha e mostrar detalhes sobre o erro quando o usuário clicar na imagem.
3. **Altere a lógica principal** que, após o passo 1, deve estar bem enxuta, para ler os vários itens sendo importados e chamar as sub-rotinas para cada um deles.

Enfim, eu sei que são passos abstratos, mas realmente não vejo uma forma simples de resolver o problema a não ser *refazer* praticamente tudo.

Se achar que nada disso vale a pena, uma alternativa um tanto mais simples, seria abrir cada importação em uma aba diferente e assim o processamento será feito de forma isolada em cada aba. Não é a melhor experiência para o usuário, mas funciona (desde, é claro, que não haja problemas de concorrência no servidor).